# How to can I add to many numbers to viber group

Tags: viber, viber-api, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

I have 50 thousand of phone numbers and I want to add all of them together to a viber community group. How can I do it?

Please answer me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Send them a SMS or message using [Viber Business](https://www.forbusiness.viber.com/) with a link to that group.